# OBS low FPS despite low CPU usage

Tags: video, graphics-card, performance, cpu-usage, obs-studio

Recently I have been getting OBS set up on my PC, so I have been playing Overwatch while messing around with OBS's settings so I could stream well. Overwatch runs well at 60-70 FPS, and my CPU (i7 4th gen[4770K?]) is less than 50%; However, OBS is capturing my game at 15-20 FPS. I did notice that my GPU (turbo GTX 1060) was at high usage because both OBS and Overwatch were using it, Overwatch was using more.

In OBS settings, I can change the CPU setting in 'output' to "lowest/placebo' in x264 or 'low latency/high quality' in NVENC and get about 45 FPS in OBS while still getting good in-game FPS and low CPU usage, so I'm 99% sure OBS can use more CPU than it is using now. I am trying to stream in 1080p 60 FPS, and lowering the output resolution to 720p doesn't have much effect on the FPS.

This may sound wierd (most people want to lower OBS's CPU usage), but is it possible to *increase* the amount of CPU OBS is using to get a higher framerate? Or is there another setting that I could enable to fix the framerate? Or is there other software like OBS (custom overlays) that can stream with my GPU better?

Comment: OBS will use as much CPU as it requires.  You don’t want to max your cpu usage if you do that Overwatch performance will suffer

Comment: Overwatch is using mostly GPU, and my CPU is barely being used, so I don't think the game will suffer greatly if I allow OBS to use a little more CPU.

Answer (score 1):

'Hardware encoding' means you're using your GPU to encode. The reason for low fps is because your GPU is probably maxing out. If you want to use CPU instead of GPU then you should switch to software encoding.

Answer (score 0):

On my "streaming rig" obs takes barely 1/10th of my cpu power using hardware encoding so you are probably fine there. Make sure you set your output to be 60fps. Maybe mess with your encoding. If its too high you might get slower speeds on twitch.

Comment: I have been messing around with hardware and software encoding, and my target FPS is at 60. I haven't actually been streaming, I wa just looking at the FPS the OBS window was outputting.